# Can you use a domain to forward web traffic at DNS to another domain but still use the MX record for this domain

Tags: webserver, dns, dns-domain

What I am attempting to do is ensure all ingress web traffic [http(s)] to `exampledomain1.com` forwards to `exampledomain2.com` but I still want to use the MX record of `exampledomain1.com` to point to at google's mail relays for mail delivery.

I know that I can do this at the application level with redirects and a web-server but in this case I will not be able to setup a physical server for A records to resolve. Do I just create the MX and TXT records for this domain without any A records and setup URL Forwarding to the URL of the second domain? Does this setup present security issues? Without hosting a web-server to redirect at the application level is this even possible?

Ultimately, a company I'm helping would like to buy up many domains similar to their name that will redirect to one master domain that represents the brand.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of how DNS and redirects work. There is no "forward" at the DNS level at all, only aliases, i.e. CNAME records. "Forwading" (redirects) work only with HTTP but in this case the domain name would need to be resolved first to an IP address using A or AAAA records or resolved to another domain using CNAME and a server needs to be setup at this IP/domain which accepts the HTTP requests and issues the redirects.

Comment: You are doing it backwards. Create the real domains and make them primary. Then either have landing pages or alias the non-primary domains to the primary.